# Missing Spring AOP libraries in STS

Tags: spring, libraries, spring-aop, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm getting my feet wet with Spring. I downloaded STS and I'm following basic examples from Spring in Action Second Edition. I'm stuck when trying to implement basic AOP and I guess I'm just missing some specific libraries in my project.

I say so because annotations like `@Aspect` are not recognized in my classes like also `<aop:config>` in my xml.

This are my Maven Dependencies:

- junit-4.7.jar
- spring-test-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- aopalliance-1.0.jar
- spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- spring-expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- log4j-1.2.14.jar

Please let me know what libraries I'm missing and where to find them.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

The following:

```
<bean id="performancePointcut"
        class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut" >
    <property name="expression" value="execution(* Performer+.perform(..))" />
</bean>
```

throws the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'performancePointcut' defined in file [C:\Users\Prova\Documents\STS\SpringIdol3\src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\spring-idol.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException

**DONE!**

This [aspectj-annotation-tutorial](http://www.andrewewhite.net/wordpress/2010/03/17/aspectj-annotation-tutorial/) did the job with steps 1, 2, and 3.

It's been a fun Friday night....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put these two dependencies in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi abalogh. I got it to work adding the libraries in STS through the project properties / java built path / libraries / add external jars. Is it the same thing or is there a particular reason why I should add those dependencies in the pom.xml instead? Thanks!

Comment: You wrote about 'Maven dependencies' - I assumed you are using Maven. If so, you shouldn't add manually jars to classpath, for one reason when you build with Maven, those won't be included in your binary.

Answer (score 2):

you may add maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```