# Spring aop java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, aop, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem with aop config. Here is part of my spring xml config:

```
<bean id="conLogger" class="com.pomkine.pXMPP.connection_service.ConnectionLogger"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="conLogger">
        <aop:pointcut id="connect"
                      expression= "execution(* com.pomkine.pXMPP.connection_service.connectionManager.connect(..))" />
        <aop:after pointcut-ref="connect"
                   method="connected"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/pomkine/pXMPP/connection_service/connection-manager.xml");
    connectionManager cm=(connectionManager)ac.getBean("connectionManager");
    try {
        cm.connect();
        cm.disconnect();
      } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When I'm runnig it I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connect': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
```

Can't figure out what the problem is. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New to Spring - Missing AOP libraries in STS, help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475313/new-to-spring-missing-aop-libraries-in-sts-help)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question: [Missing Spring AOP libraries in STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475313/new-to-spring-missing-aop-libraries-in-sts-help) seems to address a similar problem (missing libraries), also a problem in this [Spring Forum thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?43141-AspectJ-And-Spring).

Do you have the mentioned jars on your classpath?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, adding this dependencies helped                        `<dependency>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.11</version>
      </dependency>`

Comment: Why do we need these dependencies? Aren't they for AspectJ? I'm having the same problem but I don't use AspectJ, I want to use Spring AOP.